# Using R `outer` with `%in%` operator

Tags: r

I am trying to perform the following outer operation:

```
x <- c(1, 11)
choices <- list(1:10, 10:20)

outer(x, choices, FUN=`%in%`)
```

I expect the following matrix:

```
      [,1]  [,2]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE
```

which would correspond to the following operations:

```
outer(x, choices, FUN=paste, sep=" %in% ")
     [,1]           [,2]           
[1,] "1 %in% 1:10"  "1 %in% 10:20" 
[2,] "11 %in% 1:10" "11 %in% 10:20"
```

But for some reason I am getting:

```
      [,1]  [,2]
[1,] FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE
```

What is happening?

Comment: `outer` only works with binary functions that are vectorized in both arguments. The `table` argument is not vectorized.

Comment: ``outer(x, choices, FUN = Vectorize(`%in%`))`` works, but is of course only a hidden loop.

Comment: I actually thought `outer` was a (double) hidden loop, like all the `apply` functions. I understand better now: `outer` is basically `expand.grid` + `FUN` which only works if `FUN` is vectorized. Makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As expressed in the comments, the `table` argument of `match` (the function called by `%in%`) isn't intended to be a list (if it is, it gets coerced to a character). You should use `vapply`:

```
vapply(choices,function(y) x %in% y,logical(length(x)))
#      [,1]  [,2]
#[1,]  TRUE FALSE
#[2,] FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way that is close to your train of thought, would be to use `expand.grid()` to create the combinations, and then `Map` the two columns via `%in%` function, i.e.

```
d1 <- expand.grid(x, choices)
matrix(mapply(`%in%`, d1$Var1, d1$Var2), nrow = length(x))
#or you can use Map(`%in%`, ...) in order to keep results in a list
```

**OR**

As @nicola suggests, in order to make things better,

```
d1 <- expand.grid(list(x), choices) 
mapply(%in%, d1$Var1, d1$Var2)
```

both giving,

> ```
>       [,1]  [,2]
> [1,]  TRUE FALSE
> [2,] FALSE  TRUE
> ```

Comment: To make things a lot better, you should `d1 <- expand.grid(list(x), choices)` and then just `mapply(`%in%`, d1$Var1, d1$Var2)` leads to the correct result, with much less time and RAM usage.

Comment: @nicola I agree with everything you said. Only reason I posted this is because it is closer to OP's mindset for the specific problem. But yes, very 'RAM' consuming. Thank you for the alternative! Looks much better